# How to select only the individuals that appear in every year of a dataframe in r

Tags: r, select, time

I'm trying to subset the individuals that have been present for the duration of the whole study starting in 2014 and ending in 2019. So, the output would be a list of names that are present in every year of the dataframe.

I've tried the following code:

```
    big_data <- dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6) # I've bound 6 different dataframes (each with data from one of the years) by row. These dfs have a different number of rows and columns. Some columns repeat in different years, while others don't.

    Date <- as.POSIXlt.Date(big_data$Date) 

    Year <- separate(big_data, Date, into = c('Month', 'Day', 'Year') %>% select(Year)) # I've extracted the Year from the Date variable (DD/MM/YYYY)

    Year <- big_data$Year # I've added it to the big_data

    Interval <- Year %between% c("2014", "2019") # I've created a timeperiod with the start and end years of the study

    big_data [, all.names(FocalID %in% Interval)] # I've tried to get the names of the individuals (in variable FocalID) that are present in the interval (but probably doesn't mean in every year)
```

Obviously this code didn't work. Could you help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data frame has rows with `id` and `year`, for example:

```
big_data <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  year = c(2014:2019, 2014:2019, 2014:2018)
)

   id year
1   1 2014
2   1 2015
3   1 2016
4   1 2017
5   1 2018
6   1 2019
7   1 2014
8   2 2015
9   2 2016
10  2 2017
11  2 2018
12  3 2019
13  3 2014
14  3 2015
15  3 2016
16  3 2017
17  3 2018
```

You can use `dplyr` package from `tidyverse` to `group_by` individual subject `id`, and then check to make sure rows of data contain all years 2014-2019 in `year`. This will `filter` in all rows for given `id` - if all years are represented.

```
library(dplyr)

big_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(2014:2019 %in% year))
```

A base R option would be the following:

```
big_data[big_data$id %in% Reduce(intersect, split(big_data$id, big_data$year)), ]
```

In this example, `id` of 1 and 3 include all years 2014-2019.

**Output**

```
   id year
1   1 2014
2   1 2015
3   1 2016
4   1 2017
5   1 2018
6   1 2019
7   1 2014
12  3 2019
13  3 2014
14  3 2015
15  3 2016
16  3 2017
17  3 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(big_data)[big_data[, .I[all(2014:2019 %in% year)], id]$V1]
```

-output

```
#    id year
# 1:  1 2014
# 2:  1 2015
# 3:  1 2016
# 4:  1 2017
# 5:  1 2018
# 6:  1 2019
# 7:  1 2014
# 8:  3 2019
# 9:  3 2014
#10:  3 2015
#11:  3 2016
#12:  3 2017
#13:  3 2018
```

#### data

```
big_data <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  year = c(2014:2019, 2014:2019, 2014:2018)
)
```